# MaxClient Directive in apache

Tags: php, oracle, apache

we have php web application on two db linux web server connected with RAC load balancy with two Oracle db server..
we have a high traffic .. about 500 client concurrency on the same time conenct the web application ..
our linux web server is 2 giga RAM .. and 2 processors.
we want to make apache more performance ..
i have installed zend core for oracle on linux web server with prefork module.
how can i calculate exaclty the value of MaxClient directive in prefork module ..
or make any thing to improve apache performance .
or make any configration on oracle server.

Answer (score 1):

Find the average memory consumption of an Apache Process. Divide the amount of "spare" memory you have by this number. This is your MaxClients number.

When I say "Spare" memory - I don't mean "memory not in use" - I mean "Memory not in use when apache isn't running, minus about 20% for system stuff"

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how many children you are forking on startup and the MaxRequestsPerChild value you want to use, the ThreadsPerChild values, etc. It's not a simple calc.

What other values are you using?